# Filter text file using awk or sed or cut?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, cut

I am trying to fix this issue.

```
$ cat test.txt  
server1
ec2-xx.xx.xx.xxus-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Search
ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Web
ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Web
ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
server2
ec2-xx.xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
loaddb
ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
ec2dd
ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
server2
ec2-xx.xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
loaddb
ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I need output like this:

```
$ cat test.txt
server1:ec2-xx.xx.xx.xxus-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com  
Search:ec2-xx.xx.xx.xxus-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com  
Web:ec2-xx.xx.xx.xxus-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com  
Web:ec2-xx.xx.xx.xxus-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com  
server2:ec2-xx.xx.xx.xxus-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com  
loaddb:ec2-xx.xx.xx.xxus-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com  
ec2dd:ec2-xx.xx.xx.xxus-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com  
server2:ec2-xx.xx.xx.xxus-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com  
loaddb:ec2-xx.xx.xx.xxus-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Using `sed`:

```
$ sed 'N;s/\n/:/' test.txt
server1:ec2-xx.xx.xx.xxus-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Search:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Web:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Web:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
server2:ec2-xx.xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
loaddb:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
ec2dd:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
server2:ec2-xx.xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
loaddb:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

This approach uses two `sed` commands:

- `N` reads in a second line from the file and appends it to the pattern space.  This way, the pattern space always has two consecutive lines in it.
- `s/\n/:/` removes the newline from between the two lines in the pattern space and replaces it with a colon.

#### Using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR%2==1{name=$1;next} {print name ":" $0;}' test.txt
server1:ec2-xx.xx.xx.xxus-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Search:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Web:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Web:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
server2:ec2-xx.xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
loaddb:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
ec2dd:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
server2:ec2-xx.xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
loaddb:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Notes:

- `NR%2==1{name=$1;next}`

  This reads in the first and all subsequent *odd*-numbered lines and assigns the first field to the variable `name`.  It then skips the rest of the commands and jumps to start over with the `next` line.
- `print name ":" $0`

  On even numbered lines, this prints the name, a colon, and the current line.

#### Using pure shell

```
while read name; read line
do
        printf "%s:%s\n" "$name" "$line"
done <test.txt
```

Here, one line is read from `text.txt` into the variable `name` and the next into the variable `line`.  These two are then printed with a colon between them.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use the `paste` command,

```
paste -d: - - < file
```

Through Perl,

```
perl -pe 's/\n/:/g if $.%2==1' file
```

`$.` in Perl is similar to `NR` in awk. So it takes only the odd lines and replaces the newline character with `:` only on that particular lines.

Answer (score 2):

This `awk` may do, but be careful with  `getline` if you do not fully understand it.

```
awk '{a=$1;getline;print a":"$1}' file
server1:ec2-xx.xx.xx.xxus-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Search:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Web:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Web:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
server2:ec2-xx.xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
loaddb:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
ec2dd:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
server2:ec2-xx.xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
loaddb:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

This is a better way to do it:

```
awk 'ORS=NR%2?":":RS' file
server1:ec2-xx.xx.xx.xxus-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Search:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Web:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Web:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
server2:ec2-xx.xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
loaddb:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
ec2dd:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
server2:ec2-xx.xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
loaddb:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: at first, you only said that don't use `getline` function. But now you posted an answer using getline function. Why?

Comment: `getline` do works fine in this simple input, but it may fail if in case of more complex input, so its a warning that you should be careful when using it.  To downvoter: no need to give `-1` without telling why.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Updated post with a better `awk` solution.